How Can We Build Ethical and Safe LLM-Powered Chatbots for Healthcare?
The rise of AI in healthcare brings transformative possibilities, from patient support to streamlining administrative tasks. Many organizations are now leveraging chatbots powered by Large Language Models (LLMs) to provide health advice, manage appointments, and even assist in diagnostics.
However, with these advancements come critical challenges:
How do we ensure chatbots provide accurate and safe information?
How can we safeguard patient data and comply with strict privacy regulations like GDPR or HIPAA?
What strategies prevent chatbots from making “hallucinations” that could lead to misinformation?
@moraility
